# Showing Back Dated Finance Outstanding over a Power BI dashboard, where the past data may update

Tags: oracle, data-structures, powerbi, dax, finance

I have got a request from Finance team for Accounts Receivable Outstanding Dashboard, to create a possibility/ Filter to go back on the past months (at least 12 months) to show that Months Outstanding till that month.

Ex: For the Month of March 2023 my Oracle Data gives me As On Date total Outstanding always, although I should create a possibility to filter to Outstanding As On Jan 2023's month end, or Outstanding status to the As On DEC 2022.

If Outstanding are static we could have a static back dated tables saved in DB, although the data in past Outstanding also change sometime, so those backdated tables shall be refreshed.

To tackle this My Oracle team have provided Query, with provision to pass a Date as parameter to pull the Particular date's data. I have tried connecting with the query although the performance was very slow.

-I am in view to not use a Direct Query data connection to a dashboard (Power BI) with multiple calculations, that will slow down performance.
As a standard procedure I request Data Table Views with read only access and Map it to a centralized SQL data base which act as a data warehouse.

-In this case Oracle team is not able to provide it as a View ( for back dated data, which could change for past entries) hence provide a Query to pull the data
Please help me if someone has handled a back dated data scenario, Do we need to create some alternate way of data extraction structure in Oracle.

-I believe somehow I may still have to save past instances in the DB, and may have to refresh those instances at a scheduled basis to capture any changes done on past data.